# Set null arraylist Django

Tags: python, django

How can I set null or empty value of my array list inorder to insert id autoincrement , I already tried 'None' but it returns error. Can anyone help me?

> error tuple indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType

*views.py*

```
def upload_excel_file(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        person_resource = PersonResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_person = request.FILES['myfile']

        if not new_person.name.endswith('xlsx'):
            messages.info(request,'wrong format')
            return render (request,'dashboard.html')
        imported_data = dataset.load(new_person.read(),format="xlsx")
        for data in imported_data:
            value = Person(
                data[None],  // It should Empty value 
                data[1],
                data[2],
                data[3],
                data[4],
                data[5]
            )
            value.save()
    return render(request,'dashboard.html')
```

*model.py*

```
class Person(models.Model):
   person_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   covid_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   middle = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   lastname   = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
   extension  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: show your Person model

Comment: @Andrey Maslov  thank you response I've added my models above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set null value to the model field in django. You can simply assign *None* value to the *field*. So:

```
def upload_excel_file(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        person_resource = PersonResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_person = request.FILES['myfile']

        if not new_person.name.endswith('xlsx'):
            messages.info(request,'wrong format')
            return render (request,'dashboard.html')
        imported_data = dataset.load(new_person.read(),format="xlsx")
        for data in imported_data:
            value = Person(
                None,  # <--  Now null value is given to the field
                data[1],
                data[2],
                data[3],
                data[4],
                data[5]
            )
            value.save()
    return render(request,'dashboard.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just skip your auto_id_field

```
value = Person(
                covid_id=data[1],
                firstname=data[2],
                middle=data[3],
                lastname=data[4],
                extension=data[5]
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not make use of *positional* arguments. It makes it harder to read to what field what value is passing. You can use iterable unpacking an positional parameters:

```
for __, covid, first, mid, last, ext, *__ in imported_data:
    value = Person.objects.create(
        covid_id=covid,
        firstname=first,
        middle=mid,
        lastname=last,
        extension=ext
    )
```

By using [**`.create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create) you already save the object to the database in the same statement.

Comment: Thank! you it helps me a lot